# UIImage displaying duplicate images for two UImages

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a UImage view that opens and you can take a picture with it and view it in the uiimageview. But I added another image view and copied the code and now the image shows up the same as the second one. I believe it may have something to do with the '[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];'

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)
picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Get the image and store it in the image view
    image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.personimgThumbNail.image = image;

}

- (void)imagePickerControllertwo:(UIImagePickerController *)
picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    // Get the image and store it in the image view
    imagetwo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image = imagetwo;

}
```

Comment: Why you used duplicate UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method ?

Comment: I don't know is that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate delegate method which you're attempting to use is `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`.

Your second method, `imagePickerControllertwo:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`, is *not* a delegate method and will not be called automatically.

If you put in some `NSLog` statements, you'll probably find that the first method is called twice (as expected, because that's the correct delegate method).  If you want to do different things for each picker, look at the value of the `picker` argument; that's what it's there for.

Comment: I changed it to - (void)imagePickerControllertwo:(UIImagePickerController *)
picker1 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo1:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    
    // Get the image and store it in the image view
    imagetwo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    self.personimgThumbNailtwo.image = imagetwo;
    
    
    
    
}

 and its still not working?

Comment: @MatthewSuffoletto You can't just make up method names and expect them to be called.  You have to use the names in the protocol: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Comment: I still dont understand what i have to change to make it work.